# internal Component doesn't get renderd when route changes in production build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having a very strange behavior, the problem is when i build for production, this is routing logic, App.tsx:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Route path="/" component={Agents} exact />
      <Route path="/:agentName" component={Agent} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**Agents** Component get rendered just fine, no problem with that, **Agent** as well, but i have a component inside **Agent**, the **AgentProfile** Component which doesn't render and i don't know why, **Agent.tsx**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { RouteChildrenProps, useParams } from 'react-router';
import { PuffLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

import classes from './Agent.module.scss';
import Navigation from '../Navigation/Navigation';
import AgentProfile from '../../components/AgentProfile/AgentProfile';
import Abilities from '../Abilities/Abilities';
import { IAgent, getAgent } from '../../API';

interface AgentProps extends React.Props<any>, RouteChildrenProps {}

export default function Agent(props: AgentProps) {
    const params: any = useParams();

    const [agentData, setAgentData] = useState<IAgent>();
    const [isAgentLoaded, setIsAgentLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [activeAbility, setActiveAbility] = useState(0);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    // fires when url changes
    useEffect(() => {
        // do the folowing only if 'agentName' param exists(/:agentName)
        if (params.agentName) {
            // gets the id from the queryParams
            const id: any = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search).get('id');

            setActiveAbility(0);
            setIsAgentLoaded(false);
            getAgent(id).then(agentData => {
                setIsAgentLoaded(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setAgentData(agentData);
                }, 250);
            }).catch(error => console.log(error));
        }

    }, [props.location, params]);
    
    return (
        <Container fluid style={{padding: 0}}>
            <Row className={classes.HeaderRow} noGutters>
                <Col xl={{offset: 1, span: 3}} className={classes.NavColumn}>
                    <Navigation />
                </Col>
                <Col xl="8">
                    {agentData && <AgentProfile // this doesn't get rendered at all
                        in={isAgentLoaded}
                        imgURL={agentData.imgURL}
                        role={agentData.role}
                        biography={agentData.biography} />}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {agentData && (<Row className={classes.ContentRow} noGutters>
                <Col xl="6" style={{padding: 60}}>
                    <Abilities
                        abilities={agentData.abilities}
                        onClick={(index) => setActiveAbility(index)} />
                </Col>
                <Col xl="6">
                    <PuffLoader
                        size={200}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        css="margin: auto;"
                        color="white" />
                    <div
                        className={classes.Video}
                        style={{display: isLoading ? 'none' : 'flex'}}>
                        <video
                            loop
                            controls
                            autoPlay
                            onLoadStart={() => setIsLoading(true)}
                            onLoadedData={() => setIsLoading(false)}
                            src={agentData.abilities[activeAbility].videoURL}>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>)}
        </Container>
    )
}
```

I really don't know what the problem is, in the Development mode everything working just fine, the problem is in the production build, haven't found a solution.

Some screenshots, note for elements tab in dev-tools of chrome, I mark the exact line:
in development:
[image: Development]

in production:
[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';

import classes from './AgentProfile.module.scss';

const duration = 300;

const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `${duration}ms`,
    opacity: 0
};

// "in&hide" states animation styles
const agentInfoStyles: any = {
    entering: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100px)' },
    entered:  { opacity: 1, transform: 'none' },
    exiting:  { opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(100px)' },
    exited:   { opacity: 0, transform: 'none' }
};

// "in&hide" states animation styles
const agentImageStyles: any = {
    entering: { opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.9)' },
    entered:  { opacity: 1, transform: 'none' },
    exiting:  { opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.9)' },
    exited:   { opacity: 0, transform: 'none' }
};

interface AgentProfileProps extends React.Props<any> {
    imgURL: string;
    role: string;
    biography: string;
    // Animation state control, true = animate "in to the VIEW", false = "hide from the VIEW"
    in: boolean;
}

export default function AgentProfile(props: AgentProfileProps) {
    return (
        <div className={classes.AgentContainer}>
            <Transition
                in={props.in}
                timeout={duration}>
                {state => (<>
                    <img
                        style={{
                            ...defaultStyle,
                            ...agentImageStyles[state]
                        }}
                        draggable={false}
                        src={props.imgURL}
                        alt="Agent"
                        className={classes.AgentImage} />

                    <div
                        className={classes.AgentInfo}
                        style={{
                            ...defaultStyle,
                            ...agentInfoStyles[state]
                        }}>
                        <span>//</span>
                        <p>{props.role}</p>
                        <span>//</span>
                        <p>{props.biography}</p>
                    </div>
                </>)}
            </Transition>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**^^AgentProfile^^**

Comment: could you show the difference between dev mode output and prod mode with screenshots perhaps? so we could get a clearer idea of what is missing?

Comment: @lanxion done, look edit

Comment: looking at your screenshots, it looks like the initial container does render (i.e., `.AgentProfile_AgentContainer__34Vjq`). have you checked if there are missing props? perhaps the agent does not exist in production or the image has not been uploaded etc

Comment: The issue seems to be going wrong in your `AgentProfile` code, which doesn't seem to be rendering its children, initially I assumed it could be that your boolean was evaluating to false which is why `AgentProfile` was not being rendered at all, but that does not seem to be the case, Could I have a look at the code of the `AgentProfile` component? sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: also, if the data is being provided by some backend service, maybe you want to check console in devtools and also the network tab. you could be having a CORS issue.

Comment: no problem with the service, the data does get fetched and initialized, it looks like the data does not pass to AgentProfile...

Comment: i tried to console.log(props) on AgentProfile, in dev mod i do get the props, in prod not

Comment: yeah, that's what i've said and i seem to be on point. what have you tried to debug this? my guess is that the API does not return the correct information. have you tried logging the state after fetching the data on production?

Comment: yes and the state does get updated, in prod & dev mode, nothing is wrong with the API, i've check that billion times

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, i still dont know why it doesn't work, i mean it should, however i manage to make it work by changing the routing configuration, like that: **App.tsx**

```
<main>
  <Route path="/" component={Agents} />
</main>
```

then in **Agent.tsx**

```
<Route path={`${props.match.url}:agentName`} render={() => (
  <AgentProfile
    in={isAgentLoaded}
    imgURL={agentData?.imgURL}
    role={agentData?.role}
    biography={agentData?biography} />
)}
```

and it works, to be honest, it does make sense to configure the routing like that, but still, was nothing wrong with the other one. the fact that it did work on dev mode... but not in production mode. never faces such wired thing before